# Django: Place a Python function into all pages with neat code

Tags: python, html, django, function, templates

I am new to Python and Django, So I have these codes:

#### `urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

---

#### `views.py`

```py
menus = [
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "link": "/"
    }, {
        "name": "About",
        "link": "/about"
    }, {
        "name": "Contact",
        "link": "/contact"
    },
]

def gnavi():
    return {'menus': menus}
```

---

#### `gnavi.html`

```html
<nav class="gnavi">
    <ul>
        {% for menu in menus %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{menu.link}}">
                {{menu.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

#### `base.html`

```html
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body>

<header class="header">
    {% include 'inc/gnavi.html' %}
</header>
<main>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</main>
<footer>...</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

---

#### `Template Structure:`

```
+ templates
  + inc
    - base.html
    - gnavi.html
  - home.html
  - about.html
  - contact.html
  - ...
```

---

How to place **"gnavi.html"** to every page without calling it every time in "**def**" ?

```py
# ! Problem: This code works but needs to be called each time a new page is added !
# -> Which is not very nice !

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', gnavi())

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', gnavi())

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html', gnavi())
```

I want the code to only be called once but apply to every page including the page that will be created in the future.

Comment: You can use [context processor] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Comment: - Thank you for the link section.
+ RequestContext is the keyword
  - This video explain all of it https://youtu.be/_eWLaL2g1bo
- This issue has been resolved !

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`{%extends 'gnavi.html.html'%}`** in any page you want to repeat .

**for example :**

base.html :

```
{%extends 'gnavi.html.html'%}{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body>

<header class="header">
    {% include 'inc/gnavi.html' %}
</header>
<main>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</main>
<footer>...</footer>

</body>
</html>
```